# How to handle column width in 'ag-grid-react'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

When I increase the width of the div in which AgGridReact is wrapped, Grid overflows and giving column width in column definitions doesn't seem to work.

````
   <AgGridReact
            style = {{backgroundColor: "red"}}
            // isFullWidthCell =  {(rowNode) => { return rowNode.level === 1; }}
            // frameworkComponents = {frameworkComponents}
            onCellValueChanged={onCellValueChanged}
            columnDefs={columnDefs}
            defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
            onGridReady={onGridReady}
            rowSelection="multiple"
            onSelectionChanged={onSelectionChanged}
          
            getRowHeight = {rowHeight}
        
          // rowMultiSelectWithClick = {true}
          >
          </AgGridReact>```
````

Comment: Did you try resizable={true} property

Comment: Check this example:https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/column-sizing/